# FB Canvas Blank After Authentication

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

https://apps.facebook.com/canvas_starter_app/ ← please use this link to see the template in action and to see the github link to look at the source code I am trying to use.

In my scenario, it Authenticates but it's blank afterwards except for the message from the author.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: It is as hard for me to ask a good question as it is for me to figure this out.well, lets say I have static content that I want on a fb canvas. I simply want someone to be able to install the app before they see it. my canvas is always blank when I use any methods I am finding. I need a excellent walkthrough.

Comment: So you just need to check that a user is authenticated/logged in, in order to display a certain content?

Comment: No Not exactly.. Is it possible for a canvas to ask for permissions before it loads or does there have to be a login button?

Comment: or am I saying yes ... its too confusing.

Comment: I want my canvas app to be added to a persons other apps or die. This one is close but it is blank. I dont know why, unless I need to create a second index2.php file perhaps ??

Comment: Now *I'm* confused... How can you add an app to other apps?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Comment: index2.php was another dumb idea.. I'll keep guessing why this canvas_starter_app doesnt work for me.

Comment: Can you post some code? Otherwise I don't know where to look.

Comment: https://github.com/omundy/fb_canvas_starter_app

Comment: Bookmarks for quick re-engagement
If yr app is clasifd as a game and a user sts playing, we create a bmk to enble usrs to easly nav back to your game from in Fb. Bookmarks are avail on Fb hompg as well as on the Canvas Page on the top right corner.Bmks are based on how oftn and recent user used app. The counters on the bmk notfy user of outstding reqts for games and encourage them to respond.        Even if did understand the difference between a game and a canvas app, I would still want my canvas apps to be bookmarked for quick re-engagement. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: I was able to gut that template for only what it does to authenticate a user upon which it adds the app to their profile. If they click cancel however there is not way out. The original code would pull your information and display it to you, however that part never worked for me the same as the Author (see first link). I was able to display my original static html content within this php file document. Shame I didnt really learn anything more about how to use user data from this experiment. Maybe next year.

Comment: FB Docs tell one thing and do another.. https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE&scope=email,read_stream does not work for me least of which shows me the same image examples on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth Another THREE DAYS WASTED ! Maybe Next yera. or is it year idk.. burnt.

Comment: I see I have to try to Submit my app in the hope that the cancel button works for the user. Keep ya posted!

Comment: I am LIVE pending.. However, when I go to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXX directly and click cancel it redirects to the apps details. But when you do this from the tab app it keeps reloading the dialogue. Which makes sense because it is being told to do just that by the code. If I change "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($fbconfig['canvas_page']) to the apps detail page I get "...It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."